# Why can't I use .orElseThrow with ::new in Java

Tags: java, lambda

hi here is my code using Java and JPA.

```
  Club club = clubRepository.findById(clubId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID)
        );
```

and I got a code review from my collegue that I could refactor that code like this.

`() -> new ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID)` -> `ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID)::new`

but it doesn't work. I am not familiar with lambda and Method Reference..

it is impossible to refactor like that? (using ::new)

Comment: Yeah, your colleague is wrong.

Comment: I've only seen `::new` used with the class name alone, or with a parameterized type (`HashSet<Person>::new`) but never with a constructor.  It might be in the JLS but it's new to me.

Comment: Yea ... one of my pet peeves is when a code reviewer gives you a -1 on a code review telling you do something an "alternative" way *that simply doesn't work*.

Comment: @user16320675 This one can't be used at all, as it isn't a valid lambda of any form.

Comment: @user16320675 You didn't give any impression that you understood that the code provided wasn't legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your colleague is wrong. `ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID)::new` is not a valid method reference expression.

Method reference expressions can take many forms, but there are only two forms that involve `::new`. See the syntax in the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13). The two forms are:

```
ClassType :: [TypeArguments] new 
ArrayType :: new
```

In this case, the part before `::new` is `ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID)`. This is neither a `ClassType` or an `ArrayType`.

That said, `ClubException::new` would have been a valid method reference expression. If `ClubException` has an accessible parameterless constructor, then it is also valid to pass `ClubException::new` to `orElseThrow`. The parameterless constructor will be called to create a new instance of `ClubException` when the optional is empty.

So if `new ClubException()` is equivalent to `new ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID)`, then passing `ClubException::new` would achieve what you want.

Otherwise, you cannot use the `ClassType::new` form of an method reference expression.

If you really want to use a method reference expression, you can declare a method that returns `new ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID)` somewhere, and use an appropriate method reference expression to refer to that method:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static ClubException newClubException() {
        return new ClubException(ClubErrorCode.INVALID_CLUB_ID);
    }
}

//

...orElseThrow(SomeClass::newClubException);
```